# Can single photons make a hologram over time

Tags: optics, particle-physics, photons, wave-particle-duality, hologram

INTRO.
In the parallel slit experiment, single photons ejected from the source at different times still seem to interfere to make a fringe pattern, which in a sufficientliy long exposure time becomes  identical to that made by a continuous coherent light source (particle/wawe duality). 
Holograms are usually made having a continuos laser beam illuminating an object, the image of which is seen by a photographic film. At the same time the film is exposed to a non-diffracted refererence beam of the same frequency but directed at another (fixed) angle so as to form an interference pattern with the object beam. The pattern is recorded on the film as a hologram.

EXPERIMENT.
Now suppose we somehow can produce a single photon which "bounces off" the object and "hits" the extremely sensitive film producing a first "object image". Some random time later, we produce another single photon of exactly the same frequency, which we direct at a fixed angle towards the film producing a faint "reference exposure". If we repeat this process umpty-billions of times one should think - in analogy to the double slit experiment - that over time the film will contain the same hologram of the object as if continuos beams were used.

QUESTION.
Is this assumption correct, and if so how can it be proved (or disproved)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes", a hologram can be made one photon at a time.  The experiment has been done.  Of course it is a *very* slow process.  The first such experiment I read about used a photographic emulsion to capture the image over a long period of time. A standard 3D hologram recording setup was used.  The laser beam was attenuated until an average of less than one photon could be in the holographic setup at a time, and a photographic emulsion recorded the location of each photon at the hologram recording plane. (I'm searching for the paper and will post a link when I find it.)

Modern photon-counting detectors make it a bit easier; and some single-photon-on-demand emitters have been developed in recent years.  Some key words you could use in a Google search are "single photon holography" and "photon counting holography"

However, here is where the weirdness of quantum mechanics comes in: In order for a hologram to be recorded, for each photon in the recording it must be *impossible* to know or even to figure out which path the photon took (the object path or the reference path).  If *anything* is done to control or determine which path each photon takes, there will be no interference pattern.  So, if you flipped a mirror very rapidly to direct single photons down the reference or object path alternately (instead of using a beamsplitter for example), then you could not form a hologram because it would be possible to know which path each recorded photon took by detecting its arrival time.

So the answer to the question is a qualified "yes": as long as there is no way to know which path each photon takes, then yes, a hologram will be formed.  The question is actually a very good one, because a complete answer would need to explore some fascinating subjects like what a photon *is* (not the simple answer that it's a packet of electromagnetic energy), how "[EPR-based imaging](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/15/7/073032/pdf)" works, and even this [odd paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02890.pdf).

If the question is modified to allow each photon to "make up its own mind" whether to take the object path, the reference path, or both -- and to disallow anything that lets you know which path it took --, then the question still has some interesting content.  What if the reference path is a lot longer than the reference path, so we "know" that any interference that occurs is between "somethings" that were emitted at different times?

Well, it turns out that the coherence of, e.g., a Helium-Neon laser is not just the few inches of coherence length described in most specifications.  In fact, the coherence is periodic.  For a few inches before and after integer multiples of the length of the laser cavity (on the order of a few feet usually), the coherence returns.  So photons emitted *now* are neatly in step with photons emitted at time intervals determined by the laser's cavity length.  If the object and reference beams differ in path length by 3 or 6 or 10 times the cavity length, plus or minus an amount smaller than the traditionally calculated coherence length, then it's still possible to record a hologram. In effect, each photon is spread out over a distance of meters -- and over a corresponding length of time.

So, it can be very difficult, even when a laser beam has been attenuated enough that typical calculations would tell us there's only a single photon in the setup at a time, to be sure that the wavefunctions of hundreds of photons aren't present in the setup simultaneously.

Comment: Do current single-photon-on-demand emitters have narrow enough frequency bandwidths for holography? (There's certainly no theoretical reason why they couldn't, but it might hard experimentally.)

Comment: I'm not sure what the frequency bandwidth (which translates inversely to coherence length) of single-frequency sources is, but I've read that it is in some cases in the MHz range, which would translate to a huge coherence length.  See [*https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/2013-11-08/mosley_2007_pdf_12235.pdf*] . However, note that Gabor made his holograms with a filtered mercury arc source with a coherence length of (presumably) a few microns.  His holograms were subject to the same deltaX< coherence length limitation.

Comment: Can you please give a link for ""the experiment has been done". When searching I find  recordings of single photons , not a hologram constructed by single photons, which is the OP question. It needs a demonstration that the phases between sequential photons are defined.  If they cannot interfere, as your last sentence states, they cannot be carrying information of the object to be holographed, no?

Comment: I'm looking for the paper and will post a link when I find it.  My answer does not disagree with your answer.  I've edited my answer to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @anna v: In creating holograms, why do you need the "phases between sequential photons" to be defined? Different photons don't interact with each other except in very non-linear media (like a laser, certainly, but there's no need for the object being holographed to be non-linear, and the film also isn't non-linear).

Comment: In [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02890.pdf] it is shown that the wavefunctions of individual photons have an identifiable structure. The described experiment uses two-photon interference.  However, ordinary holography is due to single-photon interference (or at least is adequately described as such). But a photon doesn't really exist until it is detected (or undergoes an equivalent interaction), so in practice the distinction between single-photon and two-photon interference can be a bit vague.

Comment: @PeterShor  If there is no coherence in the photons, how can information be transferred from the reflected from the object  light beam to the atoms and molecules of the film? where will there be an increase or decrease of chemical reaction, to carry the information,  if it is random?

Comment: @anna v: If you need coherence between all the photons for holography to work, how do you explain the fact that exposures of several minutes can produce holograms, while the coherence time of lasers is measured in [milliseconds](https://www.rp-photonics.com/coherence_time.html)?

Comment: @PeterShor exposures to what? laser light, coherent point source? can you give a link? and it is not for "all photons" it is for the ones carrying information in a specific four dimensional volume

Comment: @anna v: The total period that the film is exposed to laser light during the taking of a hologram is very often several minutes. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography#Laser). And if two arbitrary photons produced by the laser during this process aren't coherent, how do the coherent ones know how to get together to form the image?

Comment: @PeterShor  but it is not arbitrary photons, it is adjacent photons. The whole thin is one big quantum mechanical wavefunction,  or density matrix  with off diagonal elements which have the intensity (number of photons in specific x,y,z,t) recorded in the superposed wavefunction, until it hits the film. So one photon at a time can still be in one wavefunction if the phases are not lost.

Comment: There is a series of MIT videos on laser , this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Ecq7hIzYU for simple interference. The whole thing is one big quantum mechanical setup.

Comment: If the definition of "photon" is taken to be "that which is detected by a photon counter in one count" (whether the counter is electronic or photochemical), then all interferometry is single- photon interference.  The spatial distribution of the counts follows the interference pattern, and each count is a single sample of that pattern at a random point ("random", of course, biased according to the probability distribution represented by the interference pattern).

Comment: @annav, I've searched the various indexes that come to mind, and haven't found the article.  Somewhere in a five-foot thick stack of photocopies of articles from journals I might have it, but it's unlikely I'll find time to find it.  It's been shown that single-photon interference builds up interference fringes in a Mach-Zehnder interferometer, which is essentially the same as a typical 3D hologram setup: http://www2.optics.rochester.edu/workgroups/lukishova/QuantumOpticsLab/2012/OPT_101/Quantum%20A%20Lab%20Presentation%202012-1.pdf

Comment: @S.McGrew  dont bother further. I do not disagree with this except for too long time intervals depending on the laser and environment  setup . With lasing, the whole thing is one quantum mechanical wavefunction, which gives the probabilities of interference. see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Ecq7hIzYU . Thus if this video was done with very low amplitude the result should be the same, except for the changes that might be introduced due to environment effects at the level of one photon which are within the error of the full beams effects.

Answer (score 0):

If you take an already recorded hologram on film, and pass single photons at a time and accumulate the results on film, i.e. put a film where the hologram forms in space, the pattern recorded on the film will be the same for single photons at a time, or a beam shining through with zillions at a time. It will be a two dimensional record, similar  conceptually to the interference pattern of [the double slit](https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) with single photons at a time.

Single photons bouncing off an object cannot form a hologram. This is because to get a hologram the phases of the photons making up the light beam have to be fixed. There is one huge wavefunction with zillions of photons where the phases are recorded in the hologram. When scattering off the object to generate the hologram,  the phases are retained with the extra information coming from the scatter off the object. There is coherence.

A single photon cannot have  a fixed phase with a subsequent  individual photon following it after scattering on the object. The phase between them is lost by the "single" requirement.

The already recorded hologram has the phase information inscribed, so a photon scattering through it follows the wavefunction that built the hologram.

**Edit after comments**.

Each photon has its own [wave function](http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002/files/0604169.pdf)

[image]

Note the imaginary part. All these wavefunctions superposed make the classical electromagnetic wave, building up the real E and B fields of the wave by the total $Ψ^*Ψ$ of the beam. When considering photons, the phases come between the wave functions of individual photons. In a laser beam the phases are fixed and  when scattering off an object   the absorptions and reflections of individual photons are in step and can be recorded on the film medium, giving a filter ( zillions of "two slits") that will reproduce the image as a hologram.

Thus the phases must not be lost for a hologram to be recorded correctly. It then depends on whether, when one photon at a time is produced, the lasing process is coherent in the time interval so that time between hits makes no difference. In my opinion , there will be differences introduced by the context as discussed in the answer [here,](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/259116/coherence-length-of-a-single-photon/259465#259465) , on coherence of single photons.

> This is genuine quantum decoherence (of the light state) and it is hard to tell what exactly the experimental outcome will be. If the whole experimental kit is genuinely time invariant, so that the probabilities of each pure state in the mixture are constant, then the answer to your question will be exactly the same as it was when we talked about energy spectral spread in pure quantum states: the probabilities of single detection events at low light levels will reflect the high light level intensities precisely. But in practice this time invariance is very difficult to achieve. You'll find that the notion of coherence length is very, very hard to measure rigorously, because the result will be highly dependent on the integration times, frequency responses, surface areas and so of in your detectors and processing electronics. You'll get a different (probably shorter) coherence length with increasing integration time, but this rule of thumb breaks down when you measure so fast that you begin to approach the "one photon in the kit at a time" régime.

So my answer reflects the latter part above, that in general coherence will be lost at the one photon stage. An experiment would show the limits for creating a hologram one photon at a time.

Comment: I understand your point about photon phase coherence so I take your answer as a no to my assumption.

Comment: As to illuminating an existing hologram (or double slits) with single randomly phased photons, I want to point out that the hologram only retains amplitude info (which of course depends on the phase difference between the original light scattered from the object and the reference beam), so your argument about the necessity of phase coherence requires that any single photon passing through an existing hologram will immediately attain the right phase relative to the next no matter what their incident phases. Is this correctly understood.?

Comment: A hologram is recorded on a film which doesn't care about the phases of photons. If you send one photon at a time onto this film, it should record exactly the same picture as if you send zillions of photons at once. You just have to make sure that each photon undergoes the proper interference, but there's no need to send zillions of them simultaneously to do this. An arbitrarily weak laser beam (with average photon number much less than 1) should do just as well.

Comment: @PeterShor  In a hologram on the film, the phases are necessarily recorded  otherwise no hologram would project  out.  One photon at a time if from the same laser and it could keep the phases even for long time intervals, you may be right. I think though that this would not be possible because of uncertainties, even the Hup delta(e)delta(t ) uncertainty will fudge the phases.

Comment: @Jens yes. It will pick up the relative phases that will generate the image in space. The reason we see images is because the photons that compose them have a specific coherence

Comment: @anna v: The phases are recorded indirectly via the interference pattern on the film. But it's not magic film that records phases—it's regular film that doesn't care whether the photons all hit it at once or not. You just need to keep the interference pattern steady, and there's no theoretical reason you can't do that with a very weak coherent laser (maybe there are practical engineering reasons, but I don't think that's what the OP was asking about).

Comment: @PeterShor  It depends on the delta(t) of the photons arrival. At some value, coherence will be lost due to physics reasons also the heisenberg uncertainty as I said. The images depend on the phases of the  photons composing the beam. The answer here  by wetsavana... is relevant  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/259116/coherence-length-of-a-single-photon

Comment: @anna: That answer is irrelevant—that deals with coherence time, i.e., how long you can delay a photon before you lose interference between the delayed photon and undelayed photon. Holography doesn't delay photons. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography#Laser) says that hologram exposure times can be up to several minutes ... and milliseconds would be extremely long coherence times for lasers.

Comment: Recording a hologram of a 3D object is no different from Young's double-slit experiment.  If the coherence length of the single photons (don't worry, I'll explain in a minute) is deltaX,  it is entirely possible to record a 3D hologram in which the reference and object paths differ by up to deltaX.  Now for coherence length of a photon: it makes some people crazy, but in an interferometric measurement of coherence length, if attenuators are used to limit a laser beam to a single photon at a time, the measured coherence length (via photon counting) is identical to that of the unattenuated beam.

Comment: Each photon takes *two* paths: the reference path and the object path, and interferes with itself on the recording medium.

Comment: Is the "two" path comment a variant of a photon supposedly being "nowhere" and "everywhere" at the same time (until measured). It does not make sense that the photon provides it's own reference beam. If true, hologram makers  could save  a lot of equipment.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a direct answer to the question, published in Phys. Rev A:
Quantum holography with single-photon states
Denis Abramović, Nazif Demoli, Mario Stipčević, and Hrvoje Skenderović
Phys. Rev. A 108, 013709 – Published 20 July 2023
https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.108.013709