# How long does an electron stay on a given orbital?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, atoms

Was wondering what the average time is for an electron on any given orbital, or how often they change energy levels.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The part of physics dealing with the motion of electrons in atoms is atomic physics, not nuclear physics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: of the order of a nanosecond for hydrogen for "allowed" transitions, and the emission rate scales roughly as $Z^2$, where $Z$ is the atomic number. For an oxymoronically named "forbidden" transition, these times increase to tens of milliseconds or fractions of a second.

So let's elaborate: what sets these times?

A point not made enough is that "orbital" is usually taken to mean an energy eigenstate of the Hamiltonian $H_0$ for the electron in a "bare" atom. So, if the "bare" atom were a true model of the atom's nature, an electron in a non-ground-state orbital *could not decay at all* (the state is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian), so its lifetime would be infinite!

The decay happens because atom systems are not "bare" like this: these systems are always coupled to quantized electromagnetic field and so the eigenstates of $H_0$ (the orbitals) are not eigenstates of the whole system.

So, to do the full calculation, one needs to know the full Hamiltonian $H_0 + H^\prime$ of combined, coupled atom and EM field. A feeling for this kind of calculation is given in [my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/86486/26076); the co-efficients in that analysis must in turn emerge from full quantum electrodynamics. But it turns out that a semiclassical analysis for hydrogen yields the right results. One thinks of the excited hydrogen as a classical dipole antenna with dipole moment amplitude $\mu$, which radiates power $P=2\,\omega^4\,\mu^2/(3\,c^3)$ where $\hbar\,\omega$ is the energy level difference for the transition, whence the transition rate in photons per second is $\Gamma = 2\,\omega^3\,\mu^2/(3\,\hbar\,c^3)$. The reciprocal  $(3\,\hbar\,c^3)/(2\,\omega^3\,\mu^2)$ estimates how long the dipole takes to radiate its photon. We need now to estimate the dipole moment. This is done (rather crudely) by multiplying the electron's charge $q$ by the mean distance between the electron in the two orbitals; this expectation is $e\,\langle \psi_1\mid \vec{x}\mid\psi_2\rangle$. Amazingly, plugging this value into our classical rate estimate in fact gives us the exact transition rate as calculated from QED; it is:

$$\Gamma_{1\to2} = \frac{4\,\omega^3\,q^2}{3\,\hbar\,c^3} \left|\langle \psi_1\mid \vec{x}\mid\psi_2\rangle\right|^2$$

For example, for the $2\,p\to1\,s$ transition, this formula gives a rate of $6.25\times 10^8{\rm s^{-1}}$, or a lifetime of about $1.4{\rm ns}$. For the $3\,s\to2\,p$ with a much, much smaller overlap $\left|\langle \psi_1\mid \vec{x}\mid\psi_2\rangle\right|^2$ the formula gives $6.3\times 10^6{\rm s^{-1}}$, or a very long lifetime of about $150{\rm ns}$.

The above are all "allowed" transitions, where the overlap $\left|\langle \psi_1\mid \vec{x}\mid\psi_2\rangle\right|^2$ is nonzero. However, all orbitals have a definite *parity*, being odd or even under spatial inversion; this means that $\psi(-\vec{x}) = \pm\psi(\vec{x})$, so that the quantity $\left|\langle \psi_1\mid \vec{x}\mid\psi_2\rangle\right|^2$ can only be nonzero if one of the orbitals has even, the other odd symmetry to cancel out the odd symmetry of the $\vec{x}$ operator in middle.

"Forbidden" transitions between orbitals of the same parity still happen, but they are much, much slower: they must decay in a two stage process, each stage flipping the parity, where there are two photons whose energy sums to the transition energy. For example, state $2\,s$ lands in the opposite parity (but higher energy) intermediate $2\,p$ state flipping the parity on a "borrowed" quantity of energy and then "pays back" the energy in making the second parity flipping transition $2\,p\to1\,s$. The transition time for this process is $0.12{\rm s}$.